# How to view the content of tempdb..#table created by other sessions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In my `tempdb` in SQL Management Studio I can see a list of temp tables such as `#A4D918A9` etc...
I can list them by code via:

```
select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O
where O.xtype in ('U')
order by O.crdate desc
```

But how can I see the **content** of these tables?
I looked all over and can't find an answer.
I also tried to use these scripts (`sp_select`): https://github.com/FilipDeVos/sp_select
But I always get an error that the table(s) does not exists.

Is this possible? if yes then how?

Comment: If see your temp table in your query  then you can get table content this code 
select * from #A4D918A9 with(nolock)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to read data in another session's temporary table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327368/is-it-possible-to-read-data-in-another-sessions-temporary-table)